# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException by RestTemplate exchange method - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, resttemplate

I am working on Spring Boot project with microservice architecture. I have a service that is talking to another service via RestTemplate. `HttpDataClient.java` class is sending `dataId` to external service and should receive something in response. For my test I should test that RestTemplate and check if I am getting good response.

Here is class that I need to test:

```
  public class HttpDataClient implements DataClient{
    
        private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpDataClient.class);
    
        private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
        public HttpDataClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
            this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        }
    
        @Override
        public DataResponse getData(String dataId) {
            try{
                JsonNode node = restTemplate.exchange(
                        String.format("/data/{0}", dataId),
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        new HttpEntity<>(buildRequest(dataId), headers()),
                        JsonNode.class
                ).getBody();
                return dataResponse(node);
            }catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
                String msg = String.format(
                        "Error getting data for dataId: {0}",
                        dataId,
                        e.getStatusCode(),
                        e.getResponseBodyAsString());
                LOGGER.error(msg);
                return dataResponse.failed();
            }
        }
    
        private MultiValueMap<String, String> headers() {
            final LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> mv = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            mv.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            return mv;
        }
    
        private DataResponse dataResponse(JsonNode node) {
            return DataResponse.dataResponse(
                    asString(node, "dataId"),
                    asString(node, "author"),
                    asString(node, "authorDataId"),
                    asString(node, "serverSideDataId")
            );
        }
    
        private JsonNode buildRequest(String dataId) {
            ObjectNode root = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
            root.put("dataId", dataId);
            return root;
        }
    }
```

Test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class HttpDataServiceTest {

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private HttpDataService httpDataService;

    @Test
    public void getData() {

        httpDataService.getData("gameIdTest");
        Mockito
            .when(restTemplate.exchange(
                    ArgumentMatchers.eq("/game/IdTest"),
                    ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                    ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                    ArgumentMatchers.<Class<DataResponse>>any()))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED));
    }
}
```

When I run the test I am getting a NullPointerException

`java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.gamedata.HttpDataService.getData(HttpDataService.java:37) at com.example.data.HttpDataServiceTest.getData(HttpDataServiceTest.java:36) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your mocked scenario doesn't match your code. `/game/idTest/` -> `/data/{0}` those are totally different and it returns a `JsonNode` not a `DataResponse`. And your mocking should go **before** you actually call the method.

Comment: Can you please give me example within my code I am not sure if I understand. Should I change JsonNode with DataResponse in my HttpDataServiceClass?

Comment: Why should you change your code? It is your test that is wrong (assuming for now your code is right).

Comment: Yes, yes that is what I thought. What is your advice to change? I am complete beginner in testing so I am all ears :)

Comment: Well for starters read a book on Junit and Mockito instead of trial and error. Assuming your code is correct your mockito mocking should match that call, currently it doesn't. I already explained in my first post what was wrong and thus what you need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least these are wrong:

- you need to do Mockito.when() stuff *before* you call the actual method. Not after.
- `/game/idTest/` is different from `/data/{0}`, they won't match but they need to in order for this to work
- DataResponse is not JsonNode, they should match, too
- in your when() call you would actually need to return something sensible to be received in HTTP body, just "Accepted" is not enough and it leaves the response body empty
- you would need to provide a reasonable json node as response

So your test method contents should be something like

```
    // create response object
    ObjectNode responseNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
    responseNode.put("dataId", "");
    responseNode.put("author", "");
    responseNode.put("authorDataId", "");
    responseNode.put("serverSideDataId", "");
    
    // prepare your mock for the call
    Mockito
        .when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.eq("/data/gameIdTest"),
                ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<JsonNode>>any()))
        .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(responseNode, HttpStatus.OK));

    // do the call
    httpDataService.getData("gameIdTest");
```

Comment: Can you please give me example in code? I am not su re if I understand.

Comment: So in this line of code in my test class should I change this  `ArgumentMatchers.<Class<DataResponse>>any()))`to this  `ArgumentMatchers.<Class<JsonNode>>any()))`?

Comment: "you need to do Mockito.when() stuff before you call the actual method. Not after." should I add this line of code         `httpGameDataService.getGameData("gameIdTest");` after `Mockito.when()`

Comment: "n your when() call you would actually need to return something sensible to be received in HTTP body, just "Accepted" is not enough and it leaves the response body empty" this one <i am not sure how to do within my code? Sorry I am complete beginner in testing

Comment: @user9347049 you're on the right track. Added some example code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. From your great answer I realized what I need to change, what I was missing. I did change it but still bot getting response back. So, when I debug I go trough test class and everything works fine, then it goes to HttpDataClient class to getData method and when I am in restTemplate.exchange I can see that dataId is sent, then it goes down to .getBody(); and it breaks. And I don’t get anything in return. Still do have nullPointException. Do you know maybe why?

Comment: @user9347049 I had body and httpstatus vice versa in my answer. switched now. But in short, there are plentyful things here that might go wrong that you will need to step them through with a debugger.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was super helpful! :)